# How to see if any of all checkboxes are checked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, jsp, jstl

I have 8 checkboxes and 1 btn i created with loop JSTL like this

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="8" varStatus="loop">
        <input type="checkbox" onchange = "x()" id="seat${loop.index}" name="seat${loop.index}" value="seat${loop.index}">
        <label for="seat${loop.index}">Seat${loop.index}</label>
</c:forEach>
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="savebtn">
```

I would like to check if ANY of the checkbox is checked, if none is checked then the button will be disabled

I know how to check if the checkbox is checked, I know how to disable the button. However, I don't know how to implement it with loop, as i haven't worked with JQUERY much before. Here's what i've tried to do.

```
<script>
function x() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
        if ($(seat+i).prop('checked')){
            alert("+1")
        }
        else{
            alert("-1")
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This code only check if my first seat is checked and ignored the rest. 
P.S: the checkboxes have to be initialized with JSTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the following bit of jQuery, which basically comes down to having a [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to get (all) [checked checkboxes](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 0
```

If you happen to have other checkboxes in your form, throw in a [class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="seat" ... />
```

```
$("input.seats[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 0
```

Setting the disabled state of the submit button can be done using:

```
$("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", disabled);
```

where `disabled` is a boolean.

Knowing this, you use it to set the submit button disabled state like:

```
$("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 0);
```

Comment: the code above is suppose to work even though I initialize the checkboxes using JSTL ?

Comment: What does JSTL have to do with Javascript?

Comment: nevermind that. Could you please explain a little bit more about your code based on my case ?

Comment: Also, i'd appreciate it if you could correct my title for me. I've confused myself there

Comment: Basically you have two questions: 1) how to check if any of many checkboxes are checked using Javascript / jQuery, 2) set the disabled state of a submit button using Javascript / jQuery. Both are answered above.

Comment: what do you mean by throw in a class

Answer (score 0):

Your code only check the first seat is checked and ignored the rest, because for checking all checkbox you need to loop through all checkboxes, which you are not doing here.

```
var count = 0;
$($('input[type="checkbox"]')).click(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
    console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
    count++;
  }
  else{
    console.log("Checkbox " + index + " is not checked.");
    count--;
  }
);

//Disable button if no checkbox is checked.
if(count == 0){
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
else{
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
}
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: what is `(index, checkbox)` ?

Comment: @KevinGuswanto `index` is the index of ckeckbox. Like you created 8 checkboxes, so there index of first chekcbox is `0`, next is `1` and so on.

Comment: And `checkbox` is the checkbox with the given `index`.

Comment: that is default, so i don't need to change it ?

Comment: @KevinGuswanto I didn't get you

Comment: nevermind that. I'm still trying to implement your solution with my code. Since i need to initialize the checkboxes using JSTL not JQUERY

Comment: But by the way. I think for every checkbox unchecked we need to do `count--`, else when the user uncheck the checked checkbox, the count will not return to 0

Comment: According to your question, you need to disable the submit button when no any checkbox is checked. So, I initialized `count = 0` and then loop through all the checkboxes to check if any one of them is checked.

Comment: When do you want to check if the checkboxes is checked. i.e., on submitting form or when any checkbox is checked.

Comment: Yes, but when the user check the checkbox, the count become 1 right ? If the user unchecked that checkbox, according to your code the count will stay at 1, therefore the submit button will still be enabled even though none of the checkbox is checked. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: on submitting form

Comment: I updated the answer. When user check the checkbox, count will increment else decremented by one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177919/discussion-between-inullpointer-and-kevin-guswanto).

Comment: This does not work properly because the checkboxes are initialized with JSTL. the problem still persists